# Binding to an element within a UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls, actualwidth

Say I have a user control like the one below, how would I bind something to the `ActualWidth` of the "G1" grid from outside of the control?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Blah">
  <WrapPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="G1">
      ...
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
      ...
    </Grid>
  </WrapPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'out side of G1' - From the same XAML file or from Code behind?

Comment: if you use the control in a different XAML file

Answer (score 2):

If you mean with outside the control, not as Content of the control, you can use `ElementName` in the Binding like so:

```
{Binding ElementName=G1, Path=ActualWidth}
```

If you mean outside the control in another Xaml file, then you can try to use the Path property if your control is in the scope of the other control:

```
{Binding ElementName=ParentControl, Path=G1.ActualWidth}
```

However I would advise against this design, because you may change the name of G1 one day, and you would never know of any bindings that might break.

Comment: {Binding ElementName=ParentControl, Path=G1.ActualWidth} doesn't work & the control is in scope - I can see the actual width of the whole control.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind to an external control where you use this user control, declare a `DependencyProperty` at your UserControl code behind and then Bind G1 to that property.
And bind the external control's property to the UserControl's `DependencyProperty`. 
It is like a 2 level of indirection.

Comment: but ActualWidth won't bind in this way?

Comment: a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313124/wpf-usercontrol-expose-actualwidth