# WPF UserControl expose ActualWidth

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, readonly, actualwidth

How do I expose the `ActualWidth` property of one of the components of my user control to users?

I have found plenty of examples of how to expose a normal property by creating a new dependency property and binding, but none on how to expose a read-only property like `ActualWidth`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is a ReadOnly dependency property. The first thing you need to do is to tap into the change notification of the `ActualWidthProperty` dependency on the control that you need to expose. You can do that by using the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` like this:

```
// Need to tap into change notification of the FrameworkElement.ActualWidthProperty
Public MyUserControl()
{
   DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty
       (FrameworkElement.ActualWidthProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement));
   descriptor.AddValueChanged(this.MyElement, new EventHandler
            OnActualWidthChanged);
}

// Dependency Property Declaration
private static DependencyPropertyKey ElementActualWidthPropertyKey = 
      DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ElementActualWidth", typeof(double), 
      new PropertyMetadata());
public static DependencyProperty ElementActualWidthProperty = 
      ElementActualWidthPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
public double ElementActualWidth
{
   get{return (double)GetValue(ElementActualWidthProperty); }
}
private void SetActualWidth(double value)
{
   SetValue(ElementActualWidthPropertyKey, value);
}

// Dependency Property Callback
// Called when this.MyElement.ActualWidth is changed
private void OnActualWidthChanged(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
   this.SetActualWidth(this.MyElement.ActualWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActualWidth` is a public readonly property (coming from `FrameworkElement`) and is exposed by default. What is the case that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: it's public for the whole control, but not for one of the specific components the control is made up of.